# How do I play a video hosted in Azure's blob container using React Azure media player?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-media-player

I have static website in Azure and have uploaded `video.mov` to its `$web` container.

I have a react app that successfully plays videos using, React Azure media player:

```
const reactAzureMp = require('react-azure-mp');
const { AzureMP } = reactAzureMp;
<AzureMP
 skin="amp-flush"
 src={[{src: "https://www.rmp-streaming.com/media/big-buck-bunny-360p.mp4" , type: "video/mp4" }]}
/>
```

What do I need to do to change this to play `video.mov`? It is one static video so I cannot justify paying for streaming media, unless I have to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the blob URL using static website endpoint (something like `https://account.z{some-number}.web.core.windows.net/video.mov`) in the `src` element and you should be able to play the video.

You can find the static website endpoint in Azure Portal. Just go to your storage account and click on `Static website` button under `Settings`.

[image]

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks! If anyone else is trying to do something similar note that .mov can't be played so convert to .mp4.